# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.find(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/wicket/request/IRequestHandler;

Tags: java, spring, wicket-8

I upgraded my application from Wicket 6.x to Wicket 8.x and getting below exception on the page redirect.

```
Root Cause

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/liquirisk-4.3.3.7-SNAPSHOT] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.find(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/wicket/request/IRequestHandler;
    at org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker.renderHead(DatePicker.java:279)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderHead(Component.java:2653)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.ChildFirstHeaderRenderStrategy$1.component(ChildFirstHeaderRenderStrategy.java:85)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:96)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.DeepChildFirstVisitor.visit(DeepChildFirstVisitor.java:51)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.ChildFirstHeaderRenderStrategy.renderChildHeaders(ChildFirstHeaderRenderStrategy.java:94)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.renderStrategy.ChildFirstHeaderRenderStrategy.renderHeader(ChildFirstHeaderRenderStrategy.java:57)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.internal.HtmlHeaderContainer.onComponentTagBody(HtmlHeaderContainer.java:171)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.onComponentTagBody(DefaultMarkupSourcingStrategy.java:70)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRenderComponent(Component.java:2491)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onRender(MarkupContainer.java:1593)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2296)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2227)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderNext(MarkupContainer.java:1454)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.renderAll(MarkupContainer.java:1654)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.onRender(Page.java:858)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.onRender(WebPage.java:126)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalRender(Component.java:2296)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.render(Component.java:2227)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:998)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.renderPage(WebPageRenderer.java:124)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:236)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:202)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:914)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:282)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:275)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:206)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hi @Federico, please vote for this question. Hope this can help others to resolve their issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a conflict and mismatch with other Wicket dependencies...

I removed the unrequired dependency of wicket-core in the specific module where I was facing this exception and added the required dependency of wicket-request in that module in order to resolve this error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-request</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```